# How to say “turns out”

Tags: translation

The “turns out” I speak of is the one you would use when recounting a discovery. For example,

> I searched for my phone all day and **turns out** it was in my bag all along!

or

> **Turns out** he was the murderer.

How would one say these sentences in Japanese?

Comment: have you tried a dictionary? and what have   you found so far?

Comment: @Chocolate Unfortunately, my EJ/JE dictionary doesn’t have anything for “turns out.”

Comment: Check out the [Resources for learning Japanese](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/756/resources-for-learning-japanese). The **Bilingual Example Dictionaries** (under Online Dictionaries) are great as they include multiple usage examples for the phrase you are looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out would usually be 結局{けっきょく}, so:

> I searched for my phone all day and **turns out** it was in my bag all along!

would become something like 一日中{いちにちじゅう}携帯{けいたい}を探したが{さがしたが}、結局{けっきょく}かばんの中{なか}にはいっていた。

and...

> **Turns out** he was the murderer.

would translate to 結局{けっきょく}彼{かれ}が殺人者{さつじんしゃ}だった。

I hope this helps! Please notify if anything was unclear, of if you'd have additional questions.